# Excellent Performance earlier yet I'm asked to go

Tags: india, performance

I'm an MBA from a premier institute and work as a manager with a big MNC. I'm responsible for handling a major area in my country.

Although I only have 3 years experience, my performance has been excellent. 
I have been receiving a lot of awards in my tenure with my company.

However, I have been facing some personal problems since April and my work has been affected.
My manager gave me a warning a month ago that if my performance doesn't improve they'll fire me.

I have worked hard in the last month, but there is an overall dip in the business across the country and of course in my region as well.
Though, he has appreciated my work during this month, the targets were not met, but that is true for all regions, not just mine.

However, yesterday, I was asked to leave and I was only told "You did not meet expectations." when I asked for clarification.

I am thoroughly perplexed. I was a top performer 6 months back and I have been asked to go now. I feel I wasn't given enough time to prove myself again.

Shouldn't there be a Performance Improvement Plan (PIP)? Or something?
Can they fire me within a month?
How do I tackle this situation without picking up a fight?

Apologies, if this confusing. English is not my first language.

Comment: For the record, your English is excellent. Better than that of many native speakers, actually.

Comment: This is not enough for a full answer, but basically as soon as a company has decided to fire you, it's not in your best to contest that. Even if you can somehow convince the company to keep you on they will always remember that they were at the point of firing you, so if they need to fire someone in the future then your name will be one of the first to come up. Cut your losses, keep your conduct professional and try to perform to expectations for the time you'll still be working there. Don't give them any excuse to refuse you a recommendation to your prospective next employer.

Comment: Did you at some point tell your boss that you were facing personal problems?

Comment: They probably just needed an excuse to downsize.  This is usually largely driven by what the managers think they can do without, whether or not its the best decision.  The company is acting like its a performance issue so that they have a legal defense if you try to sue them, likely.  They maybe doing it systematically with all the layoffs.

Comment: Unfair things happen to people all the time. Maybe your boss decided not to trust you regardless of evaluation and was to fire you at the first excuse, maybe he was pressed to fire someone and chose the one with performance issues over someone else who had been working well all year. Bottom line, you are not going to get an honest answer, and even the honest answer is of little value. You should focus in either lawfulness (this forum is not for legal issues) or in learning from the situation and moving on.

Comment: "You're only as good as your last envelope." - Silvio Dante (The Sopranos)

Comment: You had your PIP - they gave you a month to fix the issue. But what you should learn from this is that you need to address those personal issues in a more timely fashion and stop letting them so severely affect your performance. If the issue is serious enough, you may need to take some time off to deal with it or ask your boss for a temporary accommodation, but just letting performance slide with no discussion of the problem is simply unacceptable and, as you found out, will likely get you fired.

Comment: These kinds of surprises typically have either an internal or external (to you) cause.  If it is something you think you could influence, the time to do that is too late.  All of the "soft skills" of getting to know your manager well, and being a well connected person in the workplace come into consideration when choosing among a group of people that perform the work more-or-less equally well.  If you are being let go when others are retained, and you're good at your job, odds are the others are good too, but have stronger relationships.

Answer (score 30):

Make sure that all the paperwork you'd need to get your next job is in order, check to see if your manager would give you a positive reference for your next job, update your resume, and start looking for your next job.

The moment you're asked to leave, there's no real reason to have any sort of loyalty or attachment to your last company. They've chosen to cut you loose (and the end of the year's not the best time for that). At this point there's nothing left for you at your old company.

You can always prove yourself at your next job.

Comment: My problem is more of - "How can they do this?" I need to know what went so wrong? Can they even fire me within a month of the warning?

Comment: Depends on your employment contract. If you have a notice period, they'd likely have to pay you for it. It could be anything - but it would be simpler to let go of someone who had been warned for poor performance. Corporations arn't always acting in the best interest of employees. I do realise it is a shock (and it happened to me recently as well!) but working on the things you know are an issue, and *getting back up* is more important than ruminating on the past.

Comment: "How can they?" Well, as long as it's allowed by the law, They can. In no country it's forbidden to fire people. Even in France, if they want to fire you, you just have a 3-months notice. And it's probably the most rigid country in the world for that. They don't need a good reason. They don't want to play anymore with you. It's unfair. Life is unfair. Look ahead.

Comment: @Guest261 considering india, they can probably do almost anything. If you comply fully and without question they may hopefully not further mess with your career. Picking a fight is a bad idea, since there are 1000 ways a company you worked for can mess your career up permanently in india.

Comment: I'd consider adding something along the lines of "They don't need a *good* reason to fire you, they just need a *plausible* reason. If performance is low across the board, it's very likely that the OP wasn't even performing badly but there are other, often political or simply financial, reasons for the firing.

Comment: Just to add I'm in very similar circumstances, and well, I'm currently jobhunting. So if you do decide to take my advice, well, good luck!

Comment: `In no country it's forbidden to fire people.` Sure it is, @gazzz0x2z . In Portugal, you cannot fire someone *without a solid justification*. You can only terminate the position they occupy in the company ("we now have one less position for designers"), but then if you reopen the position to hire someone else the person has "the right to return" and get their job back. (In theory; in practice, you can open a new position that is a bit similar but not the same, and hire someone else for the same work.)

Comment: @ANeves, they had a solid justification, they told her that her performance was unacceptable, gave her a month to fix it and then fired her when she did not.

Comment: @HLGEM I don't disagree with that. (But that is not what I was arguing. I was arguing that there **are** places where you can't just simply be fired. Places where this is not true: `They don't need a good reason.` (Quoted from the comment that I originally replied to.))

Answer (score 13):

> Shouldn't there be a Performance Improvement Plan (PIP)? Or something?

That is completely company dependent. The HR of your company would be the best ones to answer that question.

> Can they fire me within a month?

Again, company dependent. You have to go through all the clauses of firing and resignation in your offer letter.

> How do I tackle this situation without picking up a fight? I need a
>   good reference from my boss if nothing works out here.

Have a word with your manager. Explain him your problems and the reasons for a performance dip, and how your past performance can be a nice indicator of your potential, and tell him that it was a pleasure working under him, and unfortunately you had to go through the performance dip due to your personal problems. If given a chance, can prove your worth again.

This would help you get your views forward, in a polite manner, and also would help you get a positive reference letter from your boss.

Comment: I've always gotten the impression that employees in India have basically zero rights; all the power is with the employer.

Comment: @Carson63000 It is somewhat true in the large MNC's :)

Comment: @Carson63000 You mean unlike the US, where employees have zero rights and all the power is with the employer?

Comment: @DJClayworth Have you read the questions on this site about relieving letters? In India you need your former employer's permission to get your next job.

Comment: @stannius: Indeed, here in the US the right to *leave* is so fundamental that it's overlooked.

Comment: @DJClayworth lucky I meant unlike the first-world country I live in. :-) But as stannius and Ben Voigt pointed out, there are problems for workers in India that go far beyond anything in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

Trouble happens(to stay polite).

When I was a consultant, I was blacklisted at a customer where I did overperform. 4 years later, a commercial of my firm did ask a few questions and had those answers :

1. Did an incredible job _ saved und more than 1 full FTE in maintenance definitively.
2. We don't want him anymore. Was troublesome.

The trouble in question was far less personal than yours. I had words with an influent veteran who had other priorities than my hierarchy at the customer. I sticked to my orders instead of negociating, that was a tiny mistake, but still, I'm definitively blacklisted there. And next time, I'll try to be politically more "accurate".

Happens. Sad, but happens. In that case, the only focus worth it is *your* future. Your future is another job, and if you can possibly save up a few good references in that place, it would be perfect.

Comment: I fail to see how this anecdote is relevant to the OP or how this post actually answered the question.

Comment: well, maybe the introduction is long, but it leads to the last paragraph, which answer the "what to do?" part of the question. For the "why?" part, Brandin's comment in answer to OP's text seems perfectly valid to me.